# How to make build targets on Unreal Engine-4?

Tags: c++, windows, unreal-engine4

I have blank project on Unreal Engine 4. While building for windows 32 configuration is set to shipping. Manually pressed build button and built the project. All other supported platform is unchecked except windows. But while packaging contents for windows it fails and gives the following error:

```
 Missing UE4Game binary.
You may have to build the UE4 project with your IDE. Alternatively, build using UnrealBuildTool with the commandline:
UE4Game <Platform> <Configuration>
```

From log I got to know the reason is:

```
UATHelper: Packaging (Windows (32-bit)): ERROR: Stage Failed. Missing receipt 'D:\UE\MyProject4forBuilds\Binaries\Win32\MyProject4forBuilds-Win32-Shipping.target'. Check that this target has been built.
UATHelper: Packaging (Windows (32-bit)):        (see C:\Users\X\AppData\Roaming\Unreal Engine\AutomationTool\Logs\G+Epic+Games+UE_4.21\Log.txt for full exception trace)
PackagingResults: Error: Stage Failed. Missing receipt 'D:\UE\MyProject4forBuilds\Binaries\Win32\MyProject4forBuilds-Win32-Shipping.target'. Check that this target has been built.
UATHelper: Packaging (Windows (32-bit)): AutomationTool exiting with ExitCode=103 (Error_MissingExecutable)
UATHelper: Packaging (Windows (32-bit)): BUILD FAILED
```

Here `MyProject4forBuilds` is the project name. And I have no idea after searching a lot how to solve this. This happens with other platform builds as well.

How can I build/find this missing target? How can I build my project?

Comment: How do you start your project ? by clicking the uproject, or generating SLN and opening with Visual studio ? If with VS, do you set the same  plateform in the Plateform solutions choice that the platform you try to package ? ( Win32 )

Comment: @Marcassin Thanks for reply. I'm creating a blank project from Unreal Engine startup page. I'm not even creating any script and not opening VS. I want to see if a successful project build can happen on a blank project before trying on larger project builds. ___ From tutorials on packaging I did not see it is mandatory to use VS to export on windows. Also this same issue persists with HTML and other platforms as well.___Thank you.